# Suspicious Continuity Test Result

Tags: audio, multimeter

#### *# Paraphrased Question*

When testing for continuity on an old circuit board from a usb powered desktop speaker, i find that the ground is connected to almost all other points including to each feet (anode & cathode) of the indicator LED and to each red & black speaker wires, just to name a few. With a probe on the ground terminal, the multimeter also beep when poking the other probe on every individual feet of all capacitors, resistors, the volume potentiometer, all 3 terminal from the input jack (tip + ring + sleeve) and almost every feet of the the [TEA2025B chip](http://lib.chipdip.ru/222/DOC000222904.pdf) - no beep on pin 7 & 10. Is this an indicator of a ground loop or shorted solder trace somewhere on the circuit? What other test can i do to investigate or troubleshoot this board? If this is a faulty circuit board, how do i fix it?

#### *# Original Entry*

The following is a situation that i find myself in while using a digital multimeter to learn and practice on the subject matter. Recently someone had given me a circuit board from an old computer speaker to play around and the result from a continuity test seems suspicious thus tickled some concern and curiosity over the potential, quality or possible fault of the board. With a probe on a trace labeled G (ground) the multimeter buzzed on many places poked with the other probe including both feet of the LED indicator in the circuit. Results described here are when the switch is turned on and a probe connected to ground. My confusion started when the multimeter beeped at all 3 terminals (tip + ring + sleeve) of the female audio jack as well as both red and black wires from the left speaker connection. Maybe black wires are usually all connected to the ground but when sticking my probes to the red and black wires there was no beep indicating that the ciruit is not shorted - at least not between the speaker output wires. Is this normal for desktop speaker circuit where many components are grounded or is this an indicator of a ground loop? If this is a potential problem, what other test can i perform to further ivestigate this or possibly mitigate and fix this board without using AC source or isolation transformer? This is just an exercise to help me in learning electronics and any respond, answer or suggestions (other then asking me to get a new board) towards the cause is greatly appreciated. Thank you~

Comment: You need to reformat your question. I've tried to read it and just give up after three lines. Please break it into paragraphs, include a schematic of the circuit rather than describing it in words. Mark the points you are testing, list the results along with your expectations and then ask a specific question. It will probably attract more answers then.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and i have edited out non relevant rants from the question in effort to make it more clearer. Although i am not able to include schematic diagram of the board in question, i hope that a link to the datasheet of the chip on it would suffice. Please let me know if this is still confusing - i want to be better at describing my problem in a clear question.

Comment: What brand/model is the multimeter, what range was it set to, and what showed on the display each time it beeped?

Answer (score 1):

The continuity beep on a DVM will sound if the resistance between the probes is less than some low value - mine beeps below 100 Ohms - so the continuity test is not showing a short circuit (zero Ohms) connection between the probes.

Measuring resistance on a completed circuit can give misleading readings, depending on the surrounding circuit.